# Get string name of message receiver from the inside of method

Tags: objective-c

For example I have object *department* and property *employees*. I want to have method

```
- (NSString *)propertyName;
```

such that

```
NSLog(@"%@", [department.employees propertyName]);
```

will print "employees".

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
I have an CoreData managed object *department* with relationship called employees. 
So in class I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *employees;
```

I want to create category on NSSet with method described above. The goal is to implement something like this

```
[department.employees addObject:newEmployee];
```

I woke up with this idea and I think obj-c is powerful enough to do it!

**EDIT 2:**

```
- (void)addObject:(id)object{
    id entityObject = #some magic here#;
    NSString *setName = #some magic here#;
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&object count:1];
    [entityObject willChangeValueForKey:setName withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[entityObject primitiveValueForKey:setName] addObject:object];
    [entityObject didChangeValueForKey:setName withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}
```

Wow! Looks like it's really not that simple )

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to initialise `propertyName` manually, unless you are happy to use the pre-defined macro `__FILE__`, which would include the `.m` file suffix.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see how your goal will be served by an answer to your actual question. However, Core Data already gives you what you want - see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW9).

As an aside, you shouldn't be mutating an NSSet. That's a job for NSMutableSet.